# Why the internal procedure?

Tags: scheme, procedure

```
(define (decode bits tree)
  (define (decode-1 bits current-branch)
    (if (null? bits)
        '()
        (let ((next-branch (choose-branch (car bits) current-branch)))
          (if (leaf? next-branch)
              (cons (symbol-leaf next-branch)
                    (decode-1 (cdr bits) tree))
              (decode-1 (cdr bits) next-branch)))))
  (decode-1 bits tree))
```

Why do we even need `decode-1` if we are using the same arguments to both `decode` and `decode-1`?

Answer (score 1):

`decode-1` actually refers to the `decode` parameter `tree` (in `(decode-1 (cdr bits) tree)`), not just to `current-branch`. So they're not "the same arguments". (In technical terms, `decode-1` is a [closure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_programming%29).)

If `decode-1` made no reference to `tree` (or to any outer variables, in general), then yes, you could recurse into `decode` directly and not need the internal procedure.

By the way, the "define a procedure and call it" idiom is so common, Scheme provides a ["named `let`" syntax](http://qr.ae/qp3K3) for writing it more nicely:

```
(define (decode bits tree)
  (let decode-1 ((bits bits) (current-branch tree))
    (if (null? bits)
        '()
        (let ((next-branch (choose-branch (car bits) current-branch)))
          (if (leaf? next-branch)
              (cons (symbol-leaf next-branch) (decode-1 (cdr bits) tree))
              (decode-1 (cdr bits) next-branch))))))
```

Answer (score 0):

An advantage to make such an internal procedure is that you can simply modify its implementation without changing argument count. For example, adding one extra argument as an accumulator of the procedure so that it can be tail recursive. `decode-1` is *not* proper tail recursive so if *bits* and *tree* are too big, then implementation may cause stack overflow.

Following is an example converting your `decode` tail recursive call:

```
(define (decode bits tree)
  (define (decode-1 bits current-branch acc)
    (if (null? bits)
        (reverse acc)
        (let ((next-branch (choose-branch (car bits) current-branch)))
          (if (leaf? next-branch)
              (decode-1 (cdr bits) tree (cons (symbol-leaf next-branch) acc))
              (decode-1 (cdr bits) next-branch acc)))))
  (decode-1 bits tree '()))
```

**UPDATED**

The above piece of code can also be written with named-let. So the situations when you want to write it with internal definition would be the following situations.

1. If the internal procedures have cross reference, then it can be one of the options you can choose. This can be also done by `letrec` but nest level would be slightly deeper. So in your case, `choose-branch` can be written inside of the `decode` procedure.
2. If the toplevel procedure contains internal macro defintion with `define-syntax`, then you can only write it with internal definition. R7RS's `let(rec)-syntax` creates a scope but internal `define-syntax` and `define` should be treated as if they are in the same scope.

I'm not sure if R7RS specifies how internal macros are expanded (e.g. first expands all macros like R6RS).

Comment: No, you cannot "simply eliminate the internal definition". As mentioned in my answer, the inner procedure is a closure. In fact, even your tail-recursive definition is still a closure, so you still can't hoist it out to a top-level procedure without adding an additional `tree` parameter.

Comment: Opps, sorry, I didn't notice the `tree` argument. The first 2 sentences should go.

Comment: Can you explain how the tail-recursive version works? I can't seem to understand it looking at the code... Why do you reverse acc if bits is empty?

Comment: I understood now why you reverse acc... Is it possible to do it so that you don't have to reverse it?

Comment: You can also use `append` instead of `cons` to avoid `reverse` but this costs O(n^2) since appending O(n).